# Wingspan - Player out of eggs

Tags: wingspan

In Wingspan there are certain actions which require the payment of eggs which have been previously acquired.  If a player reaches the point where any action on their part requires at least one egg and the player has none, what happens? I can't find the anything in the rules, but I would think the options are:

1. That player defaults their turn and play continues with other players.
2. The game is over.
3. The player automatically gets one egg to use for their turn (least likely event).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### A player cannot choose to take an action that requires them to spend eggs they don't have.

This means that a player with no eggs cannot chose to place a bird in anything but the first column, they cannot choose to spend an egg to get an extra card, and they cannot take any bird actions that require spending eggs.

But bird actions and spending a resource for a bonus resource are both optional, so the only full action that is outright prevented is adding new birds.  A player will always have an option to take an action that does not require spending eggs.

Comment: I was playing the game incorrectly! I/we were adding egg costs to any of the actions (gain food, lay eggs, pick a bird card), and that's wrong.  It made for some interesting strategy dilemmas, but I believe my wife and I will enjoy the proper way to play!. Your last paragraph fixes the problem!

Comment: @BillN That must have meant that players were spending most of their time on the lay eggs action.

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes, I did think that was strange. Not many bird cards were played.